# Docker unable to copy .git folder

Tags: windows, git, docker

When trying to generate a file called `head` with the current commit hash during a docker build (for internal .NET service versioning) it seems that docker is unable to pull the `.git` folder into the image at all.

Given the following `DockerFile`

```
FROM alpine/git AS version
WORKDIR /src
COPY .git/ ./.git/
RUN git rev-parse HEAD > head
```

This happens:

```
 => ERROR [version 2/4] COPY .git/ ./.git/                                        0.0s
------
 > [version 2/4] COPY .git/ ./.git/:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/.git" not found: not found
```

What is perhaps more interesting is that when using `COPY . .` it fails like so:

```
 => ERROR [version 4/4] RUN git rev-parse HEAD > head                             1.7s
------
 > [version 4/4] RUN git rev-parse HEAD > head:
#36 1.613 fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c git rev-parse HEAD > head]: exit code: 128
```

The git folder is at the same root as the `Dockerfile` as `ls -Force` (windows powershell version of `ls -a`) the following result is returned (a few folders redacted for privacy):

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         11/4/2020   2:45 PM                .ci
d--h--         3/17/2021   3:06 PM                .git
d-----          2/3/2021   6:12 PM                .github
d-----          9/8/2020   7:22 PM                .idea
d-----         1/20/2021   1:50 PM                .run
d--h--         9/29/2020   6:53 PM                .vs
d-----         3/17/2021  10:55 AM                build
d-----         11/4/2020   2:45 PM                lib
d-----          9/7/2020  11:12 AM                src
d-----         11/4/2020   2:45 PM                tests
-a----         3/15/2021   4:19 PM            340 .dockerignore
-a----          2/3/2021   6:12 PM            186 .editorconfig
-a----          2/3/2021   6:12 PM            580 .gitignore
-a----         3/17/2021   4:07 PM           1611 Dockerfile
```

Unhiding the `.git` does not change this behavior.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54150671/1890717 is a related answer that does not seem to be working here. At least on Windows 10

Comment: Curious, why are you copying the .git folder?

Comment: To get the output of `git rev-parse HEAD > head` into the final image. (we use it to detect which commit is running on various instances in production without including repository data. Very helpful)

Comment: Could you run that before the image build, save it to a file, and copy that?

Comment: We could (and do) but in the old pipeline (deploy straight to Azure App Service) this was done on build to prevent devs/ops (or devops) from messing it up by accident and having the wrong data there (which is worse then no data) so we want to enforce it in the docker builds

Comment: If you include the `.git` folder you are effectively including the entire repository  and its history in your image. Personally I'd save the output of the rev-parse command in a file in the image instead

Comment: As to the issue how is this executed? What's the working directory when `docker build` is executed?

Comment: This is executed from the folder listed in the issue (`Dockerfile` and `.git` in same folder / root of the repository)

Comment: @fredrik that is why it is only included for that step of the build and only the `head` file that is generated is copied to the final image

Comment: So you have a multi stage Dockerfile then?

Comment: I've seen it reported that disabling buildkit could solve this issue `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build ...` not sure if it would work for you

Comment: Yes, its a multi-stage docker file.

Comment: Is `.git` included in your `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: Ha, yup. VS generated that for me :)

Comment: @DavidMaze that was the issue. Thanks! I feel like a total moron as one should :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if `.git` is included in your `.dockerignore` file and if so, remove it.